# Codeigniter Count Query

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

How do I structure the below query in Codeigniter. I can't seem to figure it out.
This is the function in my model:

```
public function update_daily_inventory(){
foreach ($this->parseInventoryHtml() as $item)
    {   
        $_item = $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) as `count` FROM product WHERE product_code = "'.$item['sku'].'"');
    }
        return $_item;
}
```

I want to use an array key as the where variable. Apologize if this is simple I am new to coding. This keeps returning 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->db->where('product_code', $item['sku']);
$this->db->select('COUNT(*) as `count`');
$_item =  $this->db->get('product')->row()->count;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set alias for count.here is simple query to count number of rows found in result.

```
$this->db->where('product_code', $item['sku']);
$this->db->select('*');
$_item =  $this->db->get('product')->num_rows();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to structure your query.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('product_code', $item['sku']);
$_item = $this->db->count_all_results('product');
```

Hope this helps.